# make radio button look like it has tick and border upon active

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css

I have been trying to do something like this https://prnt.sc/20x8u7h
I have tried many a way, and can't still achieve the desired state.

I have tried to include the 1000 and uzs with a tick i class from font awesome, tried to use appearance: none;, tried working with positions, its been two days, still can't figure this out.

can you please advice how to do this?

I have been using tailwind, and tried with peer classes and it for some reason not working with my tailwind, not even finding the class ,then decided I'd perhaps better write the text myself.

I only need to make one radio button look like the one from the print, the rest I can masterfully copy+paste.

I'd really appreciate any help thanks in advance

the desired state should be: when clicked a single radio button is active and it has border with that tick on the right: -5px; top: -5px,

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h3 class="font-Rubik text-xs font-medium tracking-wide  uppercase mb-1 mt-3 text-tcolor">To‘lov summasi</h3>
    <div class="flex flex-wrap">
      <div class="relative p-2">
        <input class="absolute" type="radio" checked />1000
        <span class="text-uzs text-xs font-Rubik font-normal">UZS</span>
        <label for="1000"  class=""><i class="fas fa-check hidden"></i>               </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.tick{
top: -5px;
right: -5px;

} 
input[type="radio"]{
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 -ms-appearance: none;
 -o-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #1FBED6;
  background-color: white;

  &:checked + label{
   background: none;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use hide the `radio button` and use the icon as the check. Use grid to list the `labels` which will be positioned `relative` and will serve as a container for the icon and text inside. you can use `+` selector and get the checked `input:radio` for the first sibling `label` and style it.

```css
input[type=radio]:checked + label{
   border: 1px solid indigo;
  }
  
 input[type=radio]:checked + label > span.icon {
  display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <div>
    <h3 class="font-Rubik text-xs font-medium tracking-wide  uppercase mb-1 mt-3 text-tcolor">To‘lov summasi</h3>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-2">
    
          <input class="hidden" id="1000" name="uzs" type="radio" checked />
        <label class="block w-full border p-2 relative" for="1000">
          <span class='hidden icon'><i class="fas fa-check border border-indigo-600 bg-indigo-600 text-white rounded-full text-xs p-1 absolute top-0 right-0 -m-2"></i></span>
          1000
          <span class="text-uzs text-xs font-Rubik font-normal">UZS</span>
        </label>
          <input class="hidden" id="5000" name="uzs" type="radio" />
        <label class="block w-full border p-2 relative" for="5000">
          <span class='hidden icon'><i class="fas fa-check border border-indigo-600 bg-indigo-600 text-white rounded-full text-xs p-1 absolute top-0 right-0 -m-2"></i></span>
          5000
          <span class="text-uzs text-xs font-Rubik font-normal">UZS</span>
        </label>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hey maan thank you soo muuch, it worked.

Comment: Also, I was so down and frustrated that  I could not get the damn thing working, yet, its been more than a year I have been learning.   I went on a bit of codeless vacation kind of thing, where I wouldn't look at a single line of code, because of that frustration, but Now I am back and thank you for helping me out

Comment: Is not problem, that is why we all are here to help each other.